# Why does debug_backtrace not always return an "args" array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing some custom template logic for WordPress (which isn't really relevant, just for context). WordPress has a function wp_debug_backtrace_summary which basically just summarizes information from the stack trace.

The issue is that I'm getting a warning based on the 'args' argument not always being defined. While this looks like this is a known WordPress bug ([31215](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31215)), what I don't understand is why args is sometimes not defined.

The issue only arrises when my custom logic which uses output buffering to pre-render some template parts before rendering the whole template.

The PHP docs seem to imply that the args parameter should always be defined, and I haven't been able to find a lot that speaks to this issue.

Any help from PHP experts would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps [WordPress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be a good place for this?

Comment: I don't think this is a WordPress issue though. I'm trying to understand in what circumstances the native debug_backtrace function does not set a "args" parameter.

There is a bug in the WordPress core in that it assumes the parameter is set, but what's not clear is why it's sometimes set and sometimes not. It's not obvious in the PHP documentation - which seems to imply that it would always be set even if it's empty.